# Direct2D base code implemented by ID2D1DeviceContext doesn't work properly

Tags: direct2d

https://learn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/windows/win32/direct2d/direct2d-quickstart-with-device-context

By following above, I typed the Direct2D base code which draw a rectangle. But It didn't draw anything. What is the reason?

It is the result after making a empty project and setting sub system to WINDOW in project properties.

```
#pragma comment(lib, "D2D1.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "D3D11.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "DXGI.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "dxguid.lib")
#include <windows.h>
#include <d2d1.h>
#include <d2d1helper.h>
#include <d2d1_1.h>
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <dxgi.h>
#include <dxgi1_2.h>
#include <wrl.h>
#include <wincodec.h>

using namespace D2D1;
using namespace Microsoft::WRL;

HINSTANCE g_hInst;
HWND hWndMain;
LPCTSTR lpszClass = TEXT("DeviceContext Test");


int m_dpi = 96;
ComPtr<ID2D1Factory1> m_d2dFactory;
D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL m_featureLevel;
ComPtr<ID2D1Device> m_d2dDevice;
ComPtr<ID2D1DeviceContext> m_d2dContext;
ComPtr<IDXGISwapChain1> m_swapChain;
ComPtr<ID2D1Bitmap1> m_d2dTargetBitmap;
ComPtr<ID3D11Device> device;
ComPtr<ID3D11DeviceContext> context;
ComPtr<IDXGIDevice1> dxgiDevice;
ComPtr<IDXGIAdapter> dxgiAdapter;
ComPtr<IDXGIFactory2> dxgiFactory;
ComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> backBuffer;
ComPtr<IDXGISurface> dxgiBackBuffer;

void onInit();
void onPaint();

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance
    , LPSTR lpszCmdParam, int nCmdShow)
{
    HWND hWnd;
    MSG Message;
    WNDCLASS WndClass;
    g_hInst = hInstance;

    WndClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    WndClass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    WndClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    WndClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    WndClass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    WndClass.hInstance = hInstance;
    WndClass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    WndClass.lpszClassName = lpszClass;
    WndClass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    WndClass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    RegisterClass(&WndClass);

    hWnd = CreateWindow(lpszClass, lpszClass, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        //CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        1400, 500, 500, 500,
        NULL, (HMENU)NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    hWndMain = hWnd;
    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);

    while (GetMessage(&Message, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&Message);
        DispatchMessage(&Message);
    }
    return (int)Message.wParam;
}
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT iMessage, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HDC hdc;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;

    switch (iMessage) {
    case WM_CREATE:
        hWndMain = hWnd;
        onInit();
        return 0;
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        onPaint();
        InvalidateRect(hWnd, 0, 0);
        return 0;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
    return(DefWindowProc(hWnd, iMessage, wParam, lParam));
}




void onPaint()
{
    HRESULT res;

    m_d2dContext->SetTarget(m_d2dTargetBitmap.Get());
    auto size = m_d2dTargetBitmap->GetSize();
    ComPtr<ID2D1SolidColorBrush> pBlackBrush;
    res = m_d2dContext->CreateSolidColorBrush(
        D2D1::ColorF(D2D1::ColorF::Black),
        &pBlackBrush
    );

    m_d2dContext->BeginDraw();

    D2D1_RECT_F rc;
    rc.left = rc.top = 100;
    rc.right = rc.bottom = 200;
    m_d2dContext->DrawRectangle(rc, pBlackBrush.Get());

    res = m_d2dContext->EndDraw();

    RECT rect = { 0, 0, 400, 400 };
    DXGI_PRESENT_PARAMETERS parameters;
    parameters.DirtyRectsCount = 1;
    parameters.pDirtyRects = &rect;
    parameters.pScrollOffset = 0;
    parameters.pScrollRect = 0;
    res = m_swapChain->Present1(1, 0, &parameters);
}
void onInit()
{
    D2D1_FACTORY_OPTIONS options;
    options.debugLevel = D2D1_DEBUG_LEVEL_ERROR;
    D2D1CreateFactory(D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED, __uuidof(ID2D1Factory1), &options, &m_d2dFactory);
    // This flag adds support for surfaces with a different color channel ordering than the API default.
    // You need it for compatibility with Direct2D.
    UINT creationFlags = D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_BGRA_SUPPORT;

    // This array defines the set of DirectX hardware feature levels this app  supports.
    // The ordering is important and you should  preserve it.
    // Don't forget to declare your app's minimum required feature level in its
    // description.  All apps are assumed to support 9.1 unless otherwise stated.
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevels[] =
    {
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_3,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_2,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_1
    };

    // Create the DX11 API device object, and get a corresponding context.

    D3D11CreateDevice(
        nullptr,                    // specify null to use the default adapter
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
        0,
        creationFlags,              // optionally set debug and Direct2D compatibility flags
        featureLevels,              // list of feature levels this app can support
        ARRAYSIZE(featureLevels),   // number of possible feature levels
        D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
        &device,                    // returns the Direct3D device created
        &m_featureLevel,            // returns feature level of device created
        &context                    // returns the device immediate context
    );

    // Obtain the underlying DXGI device of the Direct3D11 device.
    device.As(&dxgiDevice);

    // Obtain the Direct2D device for 2-D rendering.
    m_d2dFactory->CreateDevice(dxgiDevice.Get(), &m_d2dDevice);

    // Get Direct2D device's corresponding device context object.
    m_d2dDevice->CreateDeviceContext(
        D2D1_DEVICE_CONTEXT_OPTIONS_NONE,
        &m_d2dContext
    );

    // Allocate a descriptor.
    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC1 swapChainDesc = { 0 };
    swapChainDesc.Width = 0;                           // use automatic sizing
    swapChainDesc.Height = 0;
    swapChainDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM; // this is the most common swapchain format
    swapChainDesc.Stereo = false;
    swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;                // don't use multi-sampling
    swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    swapChainDesc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
    swapChainDesc.BufferCount = 2;                     // use double buffering to enable flip
    swapChainDesc.Scaling = DXGI_SCALING_NONE;
    swapChainDesc.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_SEQUENTIAL; // all apps must use this SwapEffect
    swapChainDesc.Flags = 0;

    // Identify the physical adapter (GPU or card) this device is runs on.
    dxgiDevice->GetAdapter(&dxgiAdapter);

    // Get the factory object that created the DXGI device.
    dxgiAdapter->GetParent(IID_PPV_ARGS(&dxgiFactory));

    // Get the final swap chain for this window from the DXGI factory.
    dxgiFactory->CreateSwapChainForHwnd(
        device.Get(),
        hWndMain,
        &swapChainDesc,
        nullptr,    // allow on all displays
        nullptr,
        &m_swapChain
    );

    // Ensure that DXGI doesn't queue more than one frame at a time.
    dxgiDevice->SetMaximumFrameLatency(1);

    // Get the backbuffer for this window which is be the final 3D render target.
    m_swapChain->GetBuffer(0, IID_PPV_ARGS(&backBuffer));

    // Now we set up the Direct2D render target bitmap linked to the swapchain. 
    // Whenever we render to this bitmap, it is directly rendered to the 
    // swap chain associated with the window.
    D2D1_BITMAP_PROPERTIES1 bitmapProperties =
        BitmapProperties1(
            D2D1_BITMAP_OPTIONS_TARGET | D2D1_BITMAP_OPTIONS_CANNOT_DRAW,
            PixelFormat(DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM, D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_IGNORE),
            m_dpi,
            m_dpi
        );

    // Direct2D needs the dxgi version of the backbuffer surface pointer.
    m_swapChain->GetBuffer(0, IID_PPV_ARGS(&dxgiBackBuffer));

    // Get a D2D surface from the DXGI back buffer to use as the D2D render target.
    m_d2dContext->CreateBitmapFromDxgiSurface(
        dxgiBackBuffer.Get(),
        &bitmapProperties,
        &m_d2dTargetBitmap
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the InvalidateRect line or change it to ValidateRect(hwnd, NULL) after you update the window.

If you don't use BeginPaint() ... EndPaint() pair, you should definitely use ValidateRect(hwnd, NULL) or else the window will continuously generate WM_PAINT messages. EndPaint() internally executes ValidateRect(hwnd, NULL)